# table.dataChanged(index, index).connect(someFunction) fails

Tags: python, qt, pyqt, qtableview

```
table = QTableView()
model = QStandardItemModel()
table.setModel(model)
r = table.model().rowCount()
c = table.model().columnCount()
tLeft = table.model().index(0, 0)
bRight = table.model().index(r, c)
table.dataChanged(tLeft, bRight).connect(SomeFunction)
```

`AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'connect'`

Goal - to call `SomeFunction` when one of the items was changed directly by user in `QTableView()`.

What do I do wrong? I see that NoneType object cannot has attribute connect, but why it is NoneType.

Please comment. I am a beginner. Qt5.

Comment: it looks like the function `table.dataChanged(tLeft, bRight)` returns `None`. should the `connect` method be called from the `table` object? (this is just a guess, i never used Qt5)

Comment: if I apply it to model like `table.model().dataChanged(tLeft, bRight).connect(SomeFunction)` it says `TypeError: native Qt signal is not callable`

Comment: did you check the doc? which ones of your objects has a `connect` method? have you seen an example where it works?

Comment: For further reading: [PyQt5 signals and slots](http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt5/signals_slots.html). For PyQt4 and before, there another way to connect signal and slots, but it's not supported any more in PyQt5.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should do:

```
table.model().dataChanged.connect(someFunction)
# or model.dataChanged.connect(someFunction)
```

No need to precise the arguments. The slot should look like this:

```
def someFunction(tLeft,bRight):
    #do stuff
```